# ASUS BIOS Q-Fan control: Stop Fan for chassis fans is greyed, can not stop chassis fan #2

Tags: bios, motherboard, fan

In my ASUS-PRIME Z590-A motherboard I trying to use Q-Fan to control my chassis fans.
When I enter to the Q-Fan control screen in the BIOS, I see the Stop Fan checkbox, but it is disabled.

The fan is working, and the BIOS seems to be detect it and its RPM. The fan has 3 pin connector, which is connected to the mobo' 4 pin connector.

**Question**

How can I activate this possibility?

[image]

Comment: Check with ASUS Supports. The fastest way to kill a CPU / GPU is to turn the fan off. ASUS may force it to stay on.

Comment: I agree, although it is the chassis fan, not the CPU fan. For CPU fan, or water pump, there is no such a checkbox in the Q-Fan bios